# How to join an exsiting table to self-join query table?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the self-join query:

```
select g.discription, m.title 
from genre g 
join genre m on g.title = m.main_title
```

[the result of self-join (table 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLnKt.png)

This is the table that I want to join:

```
select band.name, band.genretitel
from music_band as band
```

[table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iY22.png)

the result should be like this:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAfuW.png)

My code is:

```
select band.name, band.genretitel
from music_band as band
left join (
select g.discription, m.title 
from genre g 
join genre m on g.title = m.main_title) disc
on band.genretitel = disc.title
```

and I get the wrong outcome :
[my query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/celYw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra left join to genre will get the 2nd level genre descriptions.

**Home Brew Sample Data:**

> ```
> create table genre (
>  title varchar(30) not null primary key, 
>  description varchar(100), 
>  main_title varchar(30), 
>  foreign key (main_title) references genre(title) 
> )
>
> -- First level genres
> insert into genre
> (title, description) values
>   ('Guitar', 'It uses guitars')
> , ('Hip Hop', 'Lots of words') 
> ;
>
> -- Second level genres
> insert into genre
> (title, description, main_title) values
>   ('Rock', 'Rocky guitar sounds', 'Guitar')
> , ('Blues', 'Feeling blue', 'Guitar')
> , ('Jazz', 'Jamming and more', 'Guitar')
>
> -- Third level genres
> insert into genre
> (title, description, main_title) values
>   ('Art Rock', 'Artsy rocky sounds', 'Rock')
> , ('Heavy Metal', 'Loud metal works', 'Rock')
> , ('Pop/Rock', 'Rocky pop tunes', 'Rock')
> , ('Hawai Hip Hop', 'Under the coconuts', 'Hip Hop')
> , ('Latin Rap', 'Mucho gusto', 'Hip Hop')
> ```

> ```
> -- Only one level deep
> select 
>   g.title as genre_title
> , g.description as genre_description
> , m.title as main_title
> , m.description as genre_description
> , m.main_title as main_main_title
> from genre g 
> join genre m on m.title = g.main_title
> order by m.title, g.title
> ```

| genre_title | genre_description | main_title | genre_description | main_main_title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blues | Feeling blue | Guitar | It uses guitars | *null* |
| Jazz | Jamming and more | Guitar | It uses guitars | *null* |
| Rock | Rocky guitar sounds | Guitar | It uses guitars | *null* |
| Hawai Hip Hop | Under the coconuts | Hip Hop | Lots of words | *null* |
| Latin Rap | Mucho gusto | Hip Hop | Lots of words | *null* |
| Art Rock | Artsy rocky sounds | Rock | Rocky guitar sounds | Guitar |
| Heavy Metal | Loud metal works | Rock | Rocky guitar sounds | Guitar |
| Pop/Rock | Rocky pop tunes | Rock | Rocky guitar sounds | Guitar |

> ```
> create table music_bands (
>  id int auto_increment not null primary key,
>  name varchar(100) not null,
>  genre_title varchar(30), 
>  foreign key (genre_title) references genre(title) 
> );
>
> insert into music_bands (name, genre_title) values
>   ('Metallicos', 'Heavy Metal')
> , ('Paul McSnare', 'Guitar')
> , ('The Cobbles', 'Rock')
> , ('Charlie Davis', 'Jazz')
> , ('John Lee Walker', 'Blues')
> , ('Lil Chino', 'Latin Rap')
> , ('Snoop Crab', 'Hawai Hip Hop')
> , ('The Why', 'Art Rock')
> , ('U42B1', 'Pop/Rock')
> ```

**The Query:**

> ```
> SELECT
>   band.name AS `Band`
> , band.genre_title AS `Genre`
> , genre2.description AS `Main genre description`
> FROM music_bands AS band
> LEFT JOIN genre AS genre1
>   ON genre1.title = band.genre_title
> LEFT JOIN genre AS genre2
>   ON genre2.title = genre1.main_title
> ORDER BY genre2.title, band.genre_title, band.name
> ```

| Band | Genre | Main genre description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul McSnare | Guitar | *null* |
| John Lee Walker | Blues | It uses guitars |
| Charlie Davis | Jazz | It uses guitars |
| The Cobbles | Rock | It uses guitars |
| Snoop Crab | Hawai Hip Hop | Lots of words |
| Lil Chino | Latin Rap | Lots of words |
| The Why | Art Rock | Rocky guitar sounds |
| Metallicos | Heavy Metal | Rocky guitar sounds |
| U42B1 | Pop/Rock | Rocky guitar sounds |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05618d87de0c28f955de6cfd803f932c)*

Comment: @IbrahimSaleh Something like this?

Comment: @LukStroms  thanks but it didn't work, I have rewritten my question, hope now is clear.

Comment: @IrbahimSaleh Updated. Now with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You should join two tables on *title*/*genretitel* (typo?)

```
# MySql syntax
SELECT m.name, m.genre_title, g.description
FROM music_bands m
JOIN genre g ON g.title = m.genretitel
```

Comment: thank you, Justin. still, give me the wrong output.  Here is exactly what I want to perform:

use the Genretitel from Music Band table to to get the  Genre Title_main Genre from Genre table using the Title from Genre table, for Example: 
Heavy metal in Music band table  = Rock from Genre title_main Genre in Genre table, then I use the Rock music from Titel column to get the description rock music from description column.

Comment: @LukStorms for EX: Paul McGaffin Generaltitel is Guitar, which equals Null in "genre title_main genre", then you this null and check it again in the title column in Genre table, and it should return Null.  so here we use the Title column twice,  one to get the "genre title_main genre" and then to get the description.